# Is there a more compact form of JSON for table data?

Tags: json, optimization

I have data in a table that looks something like this:

```
Col1, DataColumn
0   , 1
16  , 42
0   , 9
```

The most obvious JSON representation seems to be a list of associative arrays, but the JSON text would have `Col1` and `DataColumn` repeated in it a lot.

Is there a JSON-standard way to store this without repeating the headers?  My thought so far is to store it all as a list of lists and just know that the first row is names and the rest is data.

Answer (score 3):

Use arrays to hold the information

```
{ 
    "headers" : ["one","two","three"],
    "rows" : [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant in my final comment about list of lists.  But I'd still need to post-process it to convert it to the convenient list of associative arrays.

Comment: Why would you need to post process it? Can't the processor be extended to handle a new format?

Comment: JSON is a subset of javascript so a parser isn't needed.  Using JSON.parse is safer, however, and it's standard.

Comment: Wow, really? How amazing! [sarcasm alert]. Why is this format bad compared to the "other" way you were looking at doing it that had too much data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want compact what about:

```
{"Col1": [0, 16, 0], "DataColumn": [1, 42, 9]}
```

Comment: That's compact but I'd need to post-process it.  Otherwise, taking a row would require some sort of `map` operation.  Also, the order of columns is lost.